# UILabel Height is not updating in UITableView at launch

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am trying to set height of UILabel dynamically in the UITableView. During the launch height update is not reflected but as soon as I scroll down and scroll up back, update can be seen.

**At Launch**
[image]

> **After Scroll down and Scrolling back up again** - This what I need. See the change in text in front of player icon. I need the complete text at launch itself.

[image]

Here is the code that I am trying to use:

```
- (void) updateMessageTextForRow:(long)row ofCell:(ESGameStreamCellView *)cell
{
    NSString *item = _gameFeedItems[row]; 
    NSString *title = item ?: NSLocalizedString(@"[No Title]", nil);

    cell.message.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = cell.message.bounds.size.width;

    // Update message label height
    CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(296, FLT_MAX);

    CGSize expectedLabelSize = [title sizeWithFont:cell.message.font
                                 constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize
                                     lineBreakMode:cell.message.lineBreakMode];

    //adjust the label the the new height.
    CGRect newFrame = cell.message.frame;
    newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
    cell.message.frame = newFrame;

    NSLog(@"Message = %@, Height: %f", title, cell.message.frame.size.height);
}
```

> During Custom TableCellView Initialization

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code

    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    _message.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    _message.numberOfLines = 0;

}
```

Code for the row height

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Currently fixed height. Will be calculating dynamic height after adjusting the views.
    return 300;
}
```

Comment: have you implemented  tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath ) method ?

Comment: Yes, I am just returning height as 300 for the moment. I will be calculating the height dynamically once I solve the above bug. Will that be okay?

Comment: I have added its code

Comment: From here:
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using `autoLayout` ? I highly suspect that your `constraints` aren't set up properly: the `UIImageView` top should by tied with the `titleLabel's` bottom.

Also, you should use the new property for dynamic row : `rowHeight` and `estimatedRowHeight`.

You are getting the correct height after the `cell's reuse` : set the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` property in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` inside your custom cell class.

Comment: I am using the autoLayout and also had also set UIImageView top to TitleLabel's at the gap of 5 points. Can you point out me to some example related to estimatedRowHeight

Comment: In your ViewDidLoad method, add     self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300;
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

Comment: Looks like, your suggestion leads to me nearby. Getting some "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints". Let me try fixing them.

Comment: "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" Happens when you don't set constraint properly, You should not have any fixed height constraints on the UILabel, also try, if possible, to keep the smallest amount of constraint possible on your objects

Answer (score 0):

firstly, you should understand of the working flow of tableview delegate in objective c. Your cell height & position will be fixed after init. that's why you have to define each row's height in

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Currently fixed height. Will be calculating dynamic height after adjusting the views.
    return 300;
}
```

From this point forward, your cell's height will be fixed, even if you re-config the frame.

The best practice is some article called "Dynamic height tableview cell" and you can easily find it here

http://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift

I learn on above article (thanks for Joshua Greene) and re-write it to another library allow you to make a dynamic tableview easily. You can find it here

https://github.com/EugeneNguyen/XBMobile

it's not too perfect, but hope that if can help.

Comment: I am not worried about table cell height. I know a bit about dynamic height. Question asked is of display of UILabel

Comment: If you use dynamic height of cell, that mean you have to use AutoLayout, right? so the answer will be set your label's bottom refer to the image view. and it will push the imageView down when expand.